# I want to deploy github code in EFS mounted path

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

All Linux commands works very very slow under EFS mounted directory.

My ultimate goal is to deploy the GitHub code in the EFS mounted directory. Currently, as per the conventional way we are deploying code in the EC2 instances but as a new requirement the target is to deploy code in the EFS mounted directory. I found that the "install" event in the code deployment stage is taking Approx. 10 min time which is too much. 
As the "install" stage in the deployment unzips the code in the mentioned directory. It completes very fast when the target directory is in the EBS but it takes 10 times more time when the deployment directory is EFS. 
While troubleshooting, I found that not only unzip command, but all the shell commands are taking too much time while executing in the EFS mounted directory. I have verified the "PercentIOLimit", "BurstCreditBalance" metrics and the best-recommended configuration of EFS.

What else could be the reason behind this too much high latency?

Currently, we are using "General purpose performance mode" & "Bursting throughput mode" efs configuration.

The expectation is to execute all the Linux commands in EFS with low latency and get the throughput as same as we get in EBS.

Answer (score 1):

EFS and EBS are not the same, and your use case may want to use EFS. However you might want to rethink that. EFS will never have the same latency as EBS. Its a network file system designed to be accessed by many EC2 instances. EBS is locally attached storage, way faster by design. You should definitely not be installing programs that run across EFS on many hosts. Not what it was designed for.

EFS is designed to provide storage and to distribute files to many hosts. Executables running on EFS will be slow and a waste of resources.